# Apply maxlength for cordova dynamically created input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to load a form using cordova on an android mobile.  The below method will return the form element for the caller.  The `fldObj` will contain the field properties.

One of the property is `maxlength` which is not working.  While googling I understand that maxlength will not work and instead we have to use jQuery keyup to validate.

```
function renderBasicInput(fldObj,grpDivId){
    var strFld = '';
    var strIdVal = grpDivId+'_fld___'+fldObj.name;

    strFld = '<input type="'+ fldObj.type +'" maxlength="'+fldObj.maxlength+'" name="'+ strIdVal +'" id="'+ strIdVal +'" value="" placeholder="'+ fldObj.description+'"';
    if(fldObj.required == 'true' || fldObj.required == 1)
        strFld += ' required '
    strFld += '/>';

    return strFld;
}
```

How can I do that when rendering the input field dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve by returning an inline javascript code

```
if(fldObj.maxlength){
  strFld += "<script> .....jquery code to validate on keyup.... </script>";
}
return strFld;
```

The caller will get the input element and also a script which will validate the field for maxlength.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to bind this handler to any desired event.

Add some class like ".form-group" to the div of the input control, You can do something like this:

```
             $(" .form-group").find('input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea').each(function () {

            value = $.trim($(this).val());


            //if current input type is email and not empty, check for validity
            if ($(this).is('input[type="email"]')) {

                //Do something here
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the advice of using keyup as a solution, but I suspect that it suggests it so that you can measure the length as each character is being typed by the operator.

I tried to copy/paste your code from above but it does not get displayed properly when I edit. So I only include the changes - hopefully this makes it easier for you.

I made two changes to your strFld declaration. 1) I added a "mytest" class - call it whatever you like, but later we attach a keyup event to this. 2) maxlength becomes data-maxlength.

I created a new function called checkLength.

and lastly, the keyup event is applied. It is important this is applied AFTER you insert your input tags into the DOM. Thus, I presume somewhere you write strFld to the page (DOM). You must apply the event after you inserted the input tags.

What does it all do? See the code, then read below it for an explanation...

```
strFld = '<input type="'+ fldObj.type +'" class="mytest" data-maxlength="'+fldObj.maxlength+'" name="'+ strIdVal +'" id="'+ strIdVal +'" value="" placeholder="'+ fldObj.description+'"';

function checkLength()
{
  var maxlen=Number( $(this).data("maxlength") );

  if( $(this).val().length > maxlen )
  { alert("Maximum data input limited to "+maxlen+" characters");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$("input.mytest").keyup( checkLength );
```

The keyup event is executed everytime the user enters a character into an input box that has class mytest. The event is checkLength().

checkLength defines maxlen as a numeric variable that equates to the value inside data-maxlength. This will give you flexibility - it allows you to have different max lengths for each of your input boxes.

The conditional statement (the 'if' statement) says if the length of the users input is greater than maxlen, then shout an alert, otherwise, continue quietly. The event gets repeated every time a character is entered into an input box that has class mytest.

Lastly, try place ; at the end of all your javascript commands. Also, when you have a conditional statement, make sure to insert your actions inside a brace. Thus *if (condition) { actions }* and not *if (condition) actions* I suggest this for readability. You might know what you are writing now, but in a few months time, you'll ask yourself if the second line directly below your actions should be or should not be executed. The braces make it clear on what is and is not included. The semi-colon makes clear where a line ends!

Best of luck

(more on keyup: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ )